# AIX Shell Script - Formatting a long line of 255 Characters into a 10 line paragraph

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, aix

I am trying to find a solution (Korn Shell Script) to my problem of splitting a long line of text into a multi-line paragraph. The script will run on AIX 5.3

The text will be a maximum of 255 Characters long and is read from a Oracle table column field of VARCHAR2 Type.

I would like to split it into 10 lines of minimum 20 and maximum 30 Characters per line and at the same time ensuring that the words don't get split between 2 lines.

I have tried and so far, I have achieved the ability to split within the SQL Query itself by using multiple SUBSTR calls but that does not solve my problem of not having the same word split across two lines and hence hoping to see if this can be solved within the Shell Script.

So for example, if the input variable is

```
Life is not about searching for the things that could be found. It's about letting the unexpected happen. And finding things you never searched for. Sometimes, the best way to move ahead in life is to admit that you've enough.
```

Output should be

```
Life is not about searching for 
the things that could be found. 
It's about letting the unexpected
happen. And finding things you 
never searched for. Sometimes, the 
best way to move ahead in life is 
to admit that you've enough.
```

Appreciate if someone could guide me. Can this be achieved using sed or awk? Or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
    echo "Life is not about searching for the things that could be \
found. It's about letting the unexpected happen. And finding things \
you never searched for. Sometimes, the best way to move ahead in life \
is to admit that you've enough" |
        fmt -w 30
```

Result:

```
Life is not about searching
for the things that could be
found.  It's about letting
the unexpected happen.
And finding things you never
searched for.  Sometimes,
the best way to move ahead
in life  is to admit that
you've enough
```

Comment: @Henk . . . That was a good one...But for some reason it is not working in my installation. Basically it does not seem to accept the width parameter

Comment: maybe try `fmt --width=30`

Comment: I have tried with --w, --Width and --width but the same error fmt:bad width : 0

Comment: `[/home/u0012734] > echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/ksh
[/home/u0012734] > echo "Hi Henk How Are You" | fmt -w 10
fmt:  bad width: 0
[/home/u0012734] > echo "Hi Henk How Are You" | fmt -Width 10
fmt:  bad width: 0
[/home/u0012734] > echo "Hi Henk How Are You" | fmt
Hi Henk How Are You`

Comment: what version are you using? you do need an `=` when using long parameters

Comment: Is there a good way to show AIX Command Prompt Transcript in comments? I have dpasted it for now at http://dpaste.com/1258436/

Comment: The man page has the syntax as `/usr/bin/fmt [ -Width ] [ File ... ]`

Comment: good old AIX. its been a while possibly just `-30` without the -w --width and so on

Comment: KeepCalmAndCarryOn - Is there a way to collect each formatted line in separate variables in one single shot? Could you guide me with that please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32118/discussion-between-guddu-and-keepcalmandcarryon)

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i%6?" ":"\n")}}'
```

#### Test:

```
$ echo "$line" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i%6?" ":"\n")}}'
Life is not about searching for
the things that could be found.
It's about letting the unexpected happen.
And finding things you never searched
for. Sometimes, the best way to
move ahead in life is to
admit that you've enough.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you guys know about "man" ?

```
man fmt
```

gives a page, the top has

```
/usr/bin/fmt [ -Width ] [ File ... ]
```

thus:

```
fmt -20 < /etc/motd
*******************************************************************************
*
*
*
* *  Welcome to AIX
Version
6.1!
*
*
*
*
* *  Please see the
README file in
/usr/lpp/bos for
information
pertinent to    *
*  this release of
the AIX Operating
System.
*
*
*
*
*
*******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Also, IBM pubs is here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp.  Top hit when search for fmt is http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/fmt.htm?resultof=%22%66%6d%74%22%20

Comment: If you read the comments on the first answer, you will know that we do know "What man is" . . . It's just that the man text was confusing and we tried with -w 30 and likewise instead of just using -30 . . . Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Yea.  That syntax is used often in IBM's man pages.  You probably get it now but there is no "w" in the syntax.